# SQL - Select from two tables where equal and display two values concatenated along with a third value

Tags: sql, select, concatenation, multiple-tables

I have two tables: Classes and Courses.

Classes and Courses both have DEPT_CODE and COURSE#.

When these are the same, and in the Classes table SEMESTER = Spring and YEAR = 2018, I concatenate DEPT_CODE + COURSE# as COURSEID. I then pair it with TITLE from the Courses table.

Courses: DEPT_CODE | COURSE# | TITLE

Classes: CLASSID | DEPT_CODE | COURSE# | YEAR | SEMESTER

Select results: COURSEID (DEPT_CODE + COURSE#) | TITLE

Here was my attempt, though I'm running into some errors.

```
SELECT dept_code + 'course#' AS courseid, title
FROM classes c1, courses c2
WHERE 'c1.course#' = 'c2.course#' AND year = 2018 AND semester LIKE 'Spring';
```

I was having some trouble using semester = Spring. With the code above, I get "No Results" even though there should be valid results in the tables.

An example I hope helps clear things up.

Classes

CLASSID | DEPT_CODE | COURSE# | YEAR | SEMESTER

c001    | CS        | 400     | 2018 | Spring

c002    | Math      | 400     | 2018 | Spring

.

Courses

DEPT_CODE | COURSE# | Title

CS | 400 | Databases

Math | 400 | Linear Algebra

.

Expected Output

COURSEID | Title

CS400 | Databases

Comment: I butchered that title. "Two values concatenated and then an additional value"

Comment: The question is not clear

Comment: You can edit the title.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: try removing the single-quotes from this part (in the where clause):  'c1.course#' = 'c2.course#'

Comment: @Coding What are you unclear on? Basically when a value from the table Courses and the table Classes both share a Course# and Dept_Code, and in Classes the values for Semester is Spring and Year is 2018, I want to select (Dept_Code + Course#) and Title.

Comment: @clinomaniac The expected output is the "Select results: COURSEID (DEPT_CODE + COURSE#) | TITLE" I'd include a table, but SO doesn't have an option for that.

Comment: `COURSEID (DEPT_CODE + COURSE#) | TITLE` -> What part of this is a String and what part of this is column names? I am guessing `COURSEID` is a String?

Comment: Ah I see. COURSEID is the Column Name, which is made up of the DEPT_CODE and COURSE# Columns from the other tables concatenated. You can see an example I've crudely added to the main question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was preemptively trying to solve a non-problem with the #. Where I was wrong altogether was the syntax for concatenation. I was using + instead of ||. I'm new to SQL and didn't realize Oracle was different from others.

```
select c1.dept_code || c1.course# as course_id, title
from classes c1, courses c2
where c1.course# = c2.course# and year = 2018 and semester like 'Spring';
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing is to remove `'` from your query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(`c1.dept_code`, `c2.course#`) AS courseid, title
FROM classes c1, courses c2
WHERE `c1.course#` = `c2.course#` AND year = 2018 AND semester LIKE 'Spring';
```

Comment: This results in a "ORA-00918 Column ambiguously defined" from the SELECT line. Using c1.dept_code + c1.course#, it throws "ORA-01722 Invalid Number".

Comment: Also as I said to Aris, removing ' leads to my code breaking from the #.

Comment: Edited the answer. Try this.

Comment: This results in "No rows selected"

Comment: Check your data then. Do you have data that you would expect to see?

Comment: Create a SQLFiddle if you still have issues.

Answer (score 0):

In normal SQL, things in single quotes/apostrophes (') are just text. Therefore your WHERE clause won't return anything.

Try this:

```
SELECT dept_code + 'course#' AS courseid, title
FROM classes c1, courses c2
WHERE c1.course# = c2.course# 
AND year = 2018 
AND semester like 'Spring';
```

(if you are using SQL Server, you can put the column names in [square brackets] as well).

Comment: The problem here is the # in the WHERE clause. At least in my syntax highlighting on Sublime, # makes the rest of the line gray (commented?)

Comment: oh, it's Oracle.  Use quotation marks (") around the column name. So, c1."course#" rather than single '.

Comment: I actually got it to partially work, I was wrong about using ' or " at all in the first place. If I remove the concatenation and renaming, I get the results I'm looking for. This post has gotten a bit sloppy unfortunately

Comment: Right, you can't add an int and a string in SQL, you have to convert the integer to a varchar first.

Comment: Since it's Oracle, I was doing concatenation incorrectly. I was using + instead of ||, and # wasn't a problem as I initially thought. See the answer I submitted. Thank you so much for the help